# has_and_belongs_to association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The association between posts and users is habtm. The user_ids from the request parameter is stored in posts_users join table. I need to store the current_user id along with the user_ids which come from request parameter. When create action is called the posts_users join table will be inserted with user_ids and post id.

```
   def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.users << current_user  # To insert current_user id into join table
        if @post.save
          #success message
        else
          #error message
       end
   end


    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:content, :image, :title, user_ids: []).merge(user: current_user)
    end
```

Is there any other better way to insert current_user details into join table?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have need of storing current_user. as current_user_id is already stored in post table and with the help of that you can find the owner of the post.

```
  def post_params
     create_params = params.require(:post).permit(:content, :image, :title, user_ids: []).merge(user: current_user)
     create_params[:user_ids] << current_user.id
     create_params
  end
```

This should work :)

Comment: I need to have all the user( who have created the post and who are associated with that post in a single table)

Comment: if it is your use case then you can merge the owner_id in params

Comment: I don't know how to merge the I'd with the array of ids which comes from request.

Answer (score 0):

One way is by passing a block:

```
@post = Post.new(post_params) do |p| 
  p.owners << current_user
end
```

`.new` yields the record to the block after the attributes are assigned.

You can also create the record from the association:

```
@post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
```

But the end result is identical to:

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
@post.users << current_user
```

I would not monkey around with the params as suggested as it just muddles what is going on in the controller.